# How to detect when a particular value of a list item changes and capture the indexes into a dictionary by mapping with the corresponding item

Tags: python

I have a list like below:

```
['24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '1D', '1D', '1D', **'1D'**, **'24'**, '24', '24', '1D', '1D','24','24']
```

I want detect when the item changes from `'1D'` to `'24'` and I want to map the items to their corresponding indexes.

Like for this example the output should looks like:
`{"1d":[8,13], "24":[9,14]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
A = ['24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '1D', '1D', '1D', '1D', '24', '24', '24', '1D', '1D','24','24']
res = [[A[i], A[i + 1]] for i in range(len(A) - 1)] 
B = [index for index, value in enumerate(res) if value == ['1D','24']]
B
[8, 13] # feel free to add 1 if want to shift it to the second element position.
```

#### Edit:

A solution using [numpy](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
A = ['24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '1D', '1D', '1D', '1D', '24', '24', '24', '1D', '1D','24','24']
sequence = ['1D','24']
# get all sequences
res = [[A[i], A[i + 1]] for i in range(len(A) - 1)]
# find index of such sequence
B = np.array([[i,i+1] for i, v in enumerate(res) if v == sequence]).T

# create an dict with sequences elements as keys and their 
# values as list of indexes:
mydict = {sequence[i]: list(B[i]) for i in range(len(sequence))} 


>>> mydict
{'1D': [8, 13], '24': [9, 14]}
```

#### More readings:

[What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)
https://www.learnpython.org/en/List_Comprehensions
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-consecutive-elements-pairing-in-list/
...

Comment: Thanks @s.k . I also need the index value 8,9,13,14 and map the value against their index like {1d:[8,13], 24:[9,14]}

Comment: You'd better improve your question to include this feature in a comprehensive way. ;-)

Comment: I have updated the question @s.k